# Map JSON object to dynamically created class runtime

Tags: java, json, jackson

I was looking for a JSON library in java, I decided to use Jackson because it supports annotations and  restful web service, but if I have a JSON string and i want to map it to an object that dose not exist at compile time, i mean that I don't have the class that I have to provide in

```
Object object = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), object.class);
```

is there is a way to create the class dynamically at run time?

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree.  First learn how to deal with JSON directly, simply parsed into Maps and Lists.  Then you can use one of the fancy "POJO" tools.  And creating a class dynamically is infinitely more complex than doing what I just said.

Comment: The JAXB is another JRE Api you could use. If you mean to "load dinamically" (not create), the answer is yes. You can bind entities dinamically (if you want an example using JAXB just say) ;)

Comment: No, i mean to create the class dynamically at run time,  is this possible?